# plot a specific dataset

Tags: python, plot

I have a document set, that comes pre-tagged with specific topics/categories. These categories are hierarchical, meaning that there are 3 main categories and lots of subcategories. Each document is tagged with a set of categories.

So, I have a `n`-size list for `n`-documents, and for each document, I have a set of named categories.

ie.

```
....
['M11', 'MCAT'],
['M13', 'M131', 'MCAT'],
['C15', 'C151', 'CCAT'],
['C24', 'CCAT'],
['C15', 'C152', 'CCAT'],
['GCAT'],
['C33', 'CCAT'],
....
```

I would like to plot the category distribution of the dataset. Meaning, I would like to see the volume of each category and the relation with their subcategories, and of course the title of each category. But I don't know how to approach it.

I was picturing something like a scatter plot, but that requires `x/y` information. Or maybe something like a Venn diagram with size encoding. But my idea might not work for this kind of data.

I will be using python for this, but feel free to propose anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Unless you explain or show how we can reconstruct the hierarchy, all we can basically do is a simple counting of the labels. Also, it is important to know what you want to show. Talking about a distribution: You can count how many labels are present at each node for example  and look at the distribution of labels at each level of the hierarchy but we need to know how we can do that with your labels.

Comment: I want to show the volume of each category (how many documents belongs to it) in reference to other categories. Also I want to show if a category is a subcategory of an other category. I can't show, at least for now, how the hierarchy can be reconstruct. Only thing I know that there are 3 main categories and every other category is a child of them.